# Check if latitude and longitude lies in geofenceing radius

Tags: android, google-maps, geofencing

I'm working on an application. I need geo-fencing to check whether a particular
latitude and longitude lies within a specific radius. I'm following a tutorial on geo-fencing but my problem is that **I dont know where to pass the latitude and longitude that I want to check**

Tutorial Link:

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-work-with-geofences-on-android--cms-26639

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here

```
.setCircularRegion( LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, RADIUS)
```

When the `IntentService` detect the transition (enter, exit or dwell) on region specified the `onHandleIntent()` will be called and you can do your action (alert or anything)

Comment: the parameters passed are of my current location right? and if someone enters,exit or dwell then onHandleIntent() method will be called and I can do what I want in this method?

Comment: The Google tutorial is more clear and use Kotlin. Try it [link](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing)

Comment: I understood. Thank you.

Comment: Can you guide where I will pass the latitude and longitude to determine whether they lie in radius of my current location?

Comment: Just take example of UBER. when the customer request it creates geofences and if there are drivers in that geofence area then it sends them request. How it detects those drivers ?

Answer (score 0):

@tkrz 's formula is correct.

(lat-center_lat)^2 + (lon - center_lon)^2 < radius^2

The left side is square of distance between my location to the geofence center point. The right part is square of radius of the geofence circle.

Lets say, if the distance is smaller than the radius of the circle, it means I am standing inside the geofence area, and vice versa.

Answer (score -1):

If you only want to check this (not using mechanism for notifications) you will need some math:

```
(lat-center_lat)^2 + (lon - center_lon)^2 < radius^2
```

Comment: Your formula is correct, but how you communicate it to others is quite confusing because you didn't explain what the 2 sides of the equation do.